# Strategies to reduce the time of the tests when testing all possibilities of my algorithm

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I've made a Laravel package that generate tournament trees, and it works well.

The question is about the tests. I want to test all possibilities depending on the input parameters.

Input parameters are:

- Number of competitor ( min: 2, max: 96)
- Number of available areas ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
- Number of competitor in preliminary groups ( 3, 4, 5 )

So, if I test all possibilities, I have to make 95x5x3 = 1425 times the tests, and it takes a lot of time ( about 40 minutes )

On the other hand, if I limit number of competitors to 10 for example, I will have only 150 times the test running, but I won't be sure the test pass for all combination.

Besides, tomorrow, I could add a new parameter, for example, quantity of competitors that goes out a preliminary group ( default to 1 right now ), so each input will increase a lot the time needed.

How should I do to reduce the time needed for my tests to pass? Is there any strategy I could use ?

Comment: What might be fun and cool is "mutation testing". In mutation testing you change the production code to test your tests. That can lead to very useful insights in what you should and shouldn't test. 100% coverage is never *really* necessary, but it creates a little bit of safety. Infection is a nice library to do mutation testing in PHP: https://infection.github.io/guide/ . The examples on their website explain a bit better than what I did here too ;-)

Comment: it seems interesting indeed, I will definitively check it,  but it is more to define if my tests are significants rather that increase the rentability of my tests

Answer (score 0):

Create a few samples of these values and test those, or randomly generate a few examples and run those numbers. If your inputs are simply integers then your test should not need to be so rigorous.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    $competitors =  rand(2, 96);
    $areas = rand(1, 5);
    $per_group = rand(3, 5);
    // ... use the generated values in your code
    // ... make assertions
}
```

Comment: I thought about this strategy, but so, when I push code, my tests could pass, and the code could be wrong, so... I think testing should have predictible results.

Comment: Well this would be an integration test. Unit tests should test each individual method and function.